# Graceful pod termination

Tags: kubernetes

I need to let the container to run 5 minutes after the `kubectl` ' termination. It needs to do some work before it's destroyed. It seems that kubernetes contains exactly what I need:

```
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
```

so I defined it within my yaml. I've updated running `RCs`, delete current pods so new ones were created and now I can see that a pod contains exactly this setting via `get pod xyz -o=yaml`.

Unfortunately, when I tried to do `rolling-update`, the original pod was killed after exactly 1 minute, not after 5 minutes. I does ssh to the target machine and I could see that docker termineted the container after this time.

I tried to do some investigation how the feature works. I finally found the documentation to `kubectl delete` where there is a notion about graceful termination period:

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/

> By default, all deletes are graceful within 30 seconds. The kubectl delete command supports the --grace-period= option which allows a user to override the default and specify their own value. The value 0 indicates that delete should be immediate, and removes the pod in the API immediately so a new pod can be created with the same name. On the node pods that are set to terminate immediately will still be given a small grace period before being force killed

So I took one pod, nginx, and try to delete it with `grace-period=30`. It turned out, that original pod was immediately delete and `get pods` showed that new one was being started.

So no 30 seconds. What am I doing wrong? It seems that all pods kubernetes does not take these values into account.
Note that I'm using kubernetes v1.2.2

I also found this issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24695 where the reporter had same problem and he solved it in the same fashion. So e.g. 300 seconds is not too much for kubernetes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [container lifecycle hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks) `preStop` to have your pod sleep before terminating. This hook will be executed prior to `kubectl` sending `SIGTERM` to your container.

Example configuration from [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sleep","300"]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pracucci.com/graceful-shutdown-of-kubernetes-pods.html
may this can help you.

There’re some circumstances where a SIGTERM violently kill the application, vanishing all your efforts to gracefully shutdown it. Nginx, for example, quickly exit on SIGTERM.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.