# Postgres connection refused (via CloudSQL proxy) when doing rolling update Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

When I do a rolling update, I get exceptions from Sentry saying:

`DatabaseError('server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.',...)`

I have two containers running inside each Pod, my `app` container and a `cloudsql-proxy` container, which the `app` container uses to communicate to Cloud SQL.

Is there a way to make sure that my app container goes down first during the 30 seconds of grace period (terminationGracePeriodSeconds)?

In other words, I want to drain the connections and have all the current requests finish before the `cloudsql-proxy` is taken out.

It would be ideal if I could specify that the `app` container be taken down first during the 30 seconds of grace period, and then the `cloudsql-proxy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493043/graceful-pod-termination) suggests setting the [“terminationGracePeriodSeconds”](https://pracucci.com/graceful-shutdown-of-kubernetes-pods.html) or the ["PreStop hook"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) in the manifest.

Another idea that could work is running the two containers in different pods to allow granular control over the [rolling update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update-intro/). You might also want to consider using [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use) on your deployment to allow the proxy to be ready before your app container.