# uwsgi master graceful shutdown

Tags: python, kubernetes, uwsgi

I'm running uwsgi+flask application, 
The app is running as a k8s pod.

When i deploy a new pod (a new version), the existing pod get SIGTERM.

This causes the master to stop accepting new connection **at the same moment**, what causes issues as the LB still pass requests to the pod (for a few more seconds).

I would like the master to wait 30 sec BEFORE stop accepting new connections (When getting SIGTERM) but couldn't find a way, is it possible?

My uwsgi.ini file:
[uwsgi]

```
;https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTP.html
http = :8080
wsgi-file = main.py
callable = wsgi_application
processes = 2
enable-threads = true
master = true
reload-mercy = 30
worker-reload-mercy = 30
log-5xx = true
log-4xx = true
disable-logging = true
stats = 127.0.0.1:1717
stats-http = true
single-interpreter= true
;https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/615
http-keepalive=true
add-header = Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like this is not possible to achieve using uwsgi:

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1974

The solution - (as mentioned on this kubernetes issue):

https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/1140

Is to use the prestop hook, quite ugly but will help to achieve zero downtime:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sleep","5"]
```

The template is taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39493421/3659858

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the CLI option:

```
--hook-master-start "unix_signal:15 gracefully_kill_them_all"
```

or in the .ini file (remove the double quotes):

```
hook-master-start = unix_signal:15 gracefully_kill_them_all
```

which will gracefully terminate workers after receiving a SIGTERM (signal 15).

See the following for [reference](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/849#issuecomment-118869386).

When I tried the above though, it didn't work as expected from within a docker container. Instead, you can also use uWSGI's [Master FIFO](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MasterFIFO.html) file. The Master FIFO file can be specified like:

```
--master-fifo <filename>
```

or

```
master-fifo = /tmp/master-fifo
```

Then you can simply write a `q` character to the file and it will gracefully shut down your workers before exiting.

Comment: For some reason having `hook-master-start = "unix_signal:15 gracefully_kill_them_all"` in the ini file doesn't seem to work. I'm getting this error: `hook action not found: "unix_signal`.